# Eventlog listener - Applications and Services

Tags: c#, windows, windows-vista, event-log

Is there a way to watch events of "applications and services" when they are generated (in C#)?
I've figured out that I can not use WMI for it.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can subscribe to [EventLog.EntryWritten Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> Occurs when an entry is written to an event log on the local computer.

From MSDN:

```
    ....
    EventLog myNewLog = new EventLog();
    myNewLog.Log = "MyCustomLog";                      

    myNewLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(MyOnEntryWritten);
    myNewLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;                 

}       

public static void MyOnEntryWritten(object source, EntryWrittenEventArgs e){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did your try it wit the [EventLog.EntryWritten Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten.aspx)?