# .NET, how to attach or Intercept to Events for System Event Logging?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have got some code written, based on MSDN on how to enumerate the Event logs... but it takes ages and I can only run it once in any other time, since it really takes allot of overhead if there a hundreds of thousands of logs.

Is there a way to bind, listen or intercept the event as they come in to the Event Logger? Like a real time listener, way?

This way I can just filter what I need and do things as they happen, when it might be the most critical.

Comment: You might be better off purchasing an [existing solution](http://www.eventlogxp.com/features.html) -- I'm not paid by them, I simply provide this link as an example of what's available.

Comment: Very interesting, I might use some of those ideas in my project. If they can do it so can I :) Thanks for the link but there must be a way I can do this in .NET without installing a whole depended suite of software.

Comment: How about this [homemade cake](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10130369/815938)? Like running the code in an auto start windows service.

Comment: Ahhh! That is what I was looking for just the OP worded it wierdly. No wonder I couldn't find it. That is brilliant :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eventlog listener - Applications and Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129446/eventlog-listener-applications-and-services)